# Meaning of "native bottoms" in Thoreau's Walden

Tags: literature

I'm not sure what *native bottoms* means in this paragraph from Thoreau's Walden. Is it a nautical term? Would someone kindly shed some light on this? Search results on the matter are... ahem... questionable.

> I have always endeavored to acquire strict business habits; they are indispensable to every man. If your trade is with the Celestial Empire, then some small counting house on the coast, in some Salem harbor, will be fixture enough. You will export such articles as the country affords, purely native products, much ice and pine timber and a little granite, always in **native bottoms**. These will be good ventures.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's definition 4b(a) in the full OED...

> *A ship, boat, or other vessel.* (Now chiefly historical.)

...but that's behind a paywall for most, so here's [dictionary.com's](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bottom) definition 8...

> (in literary or commercial contexts) *a boat or ship.*

I imagine the usage arose by extension from earlier ***bottom*** = the keel or lower part of a ship's hull (OED definition 4a). That's the part of a ship most often used for carrying bulky cargo, so in contexts where the *primary purpose* of the ship is to carry that cargo, it would be natural to use the name of the cargo-carrying part to represent the whole ship.

Answer (score 7):

I did find this archaic meaning for **bottom**

> **1.9** *archaic* A ship, especially a cargo carrier.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bottom)

Comment: Not archaic, just a technical term used in shipping & naval construction, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bottom

Comment: @jamesqf - Take another look at the Oxford. It lists "**1.9** A ship" as archaic, just after definition "**1.8** The keel or hull of a ship. '_the double bottoms of the ship_'". And this question refers to the vessel.

Comment: @Nigel Touch: I'm sure that someone with better Google skills than I have could find a current example that fits the OED's 1.9 definition.  Point is, it's not actually archaic, just specialized.